# AWS DataPipeline Maching Learning AMI tensorflow issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tensorflow, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm running the AWS Machine Learning AMI on an EC2 instance. I've confirmed that from the terminal, both in python and jupyter can run

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

along with

```
python pytest.py
```

from the terminal (which contains the above tensorflow import), with no issues.

I'm now trying to automate my script using DataPipeline along with TaskRunner. The bash command in DataPipeline is again, just:

```
python pytest.py
```

However, Immediately get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pytest.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in
>   
>       from tensorflow.python import *   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line
>   72, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line
>   61, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description) ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

It seems like AWS DataPipeline (or TaskRunner?) uses a different enviornment setup, because again, I have no issues running the script through an ssh terminal to the instance. I found a few posts which suggested adding cuda to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but the AMI instance already has it:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/home/ec2-user/src/torch/install/lib:/home/ec2-user/src/cntk/bindings/python/cntk/libs:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/mpi/lib:/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/mklml_lnx_2017.0.1.20161005/lib:
```

which clearly contains the cuda librarypath that tensorflow needs.

Comment: Whether the instance has it in the default environment variable is unrelated to whether TaskRunner will not override it. Is there a way for you to force it to be there by say making your command be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...cuda... python pytest.py`?